# How can i make changes at source code of a webpage without disappearing at refresh?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to edit and source code , my question is , it's possible to refresh without losing my source code and without saving the webpage at my local machine ?

An example:

```
<span class="vx_text-1 cw_tile-currency test_balance-tile-currency">0,00&nbsp;EUR</span>
```

making all the changes:

```
<span class="vx_text-1 cw_tile-currency test_balance-tile-currency">189,23&nbsp;EUR</span>
```

When i refresh i want to appear the second one.

Comment: What would be the point of refresh in this case?

Comment: There's no point , but i wan't to know if it's possible to do something like that

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by using **sessionStorage** or **localStorage**,
see : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <span id="memo">0,00&nbsp;EUR</span>

  <button id="bt_Change"> change value and memorise it </button>

  <script>
    const  Val_X = '189,23&nbsp;EUR';

    var memoVal = localStorage.getItem('memo');  // or sessionStorage

    if (memoVal) { memo.innerHTML = memoVal }

    bt_Change.onclick = function() {
      memo.innerHTML = Val_X;
      localStorage.setItem('memo', Val_X);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Should i use tampermonkey or something else to run the script ?

Comment: I don't  know, sessionStorage or localStorage may be not accepted for security of these tools, but you can just create your own page on local to test this code ( I have changed my example)

Comment: @Claudiu so... did you test it ?

Comment: did you test it on FireFox ? use the debugger to see values in the storage part ?